# VLookup? Referencing from different sheets, multiple columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I need help with this:

Let's say I have two sheets in the same workbook.

**Sheet 1:**

```
A       //       1-Sep-13       //   
A       //       2-Sep-13       //
A       //       3-Sep-13       //
A       //       5-Sep-13       //
B       //       2-Sep-13       //
B       //       5-Sep-13       //
C       //       5-Sep-13       //
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
A       //       1-Sep-13       //       Red       
A       //       2-Sep-13       //       Blue
B       //       3-Sep-13       //       Green
C       //       5-Sep-13       //       Yellow
```

How do I auto update Sheet 1 with the information in Column 3, Sheet 2?

Comment: You can use `Index/Match` or `Index/Sumproduct` to do a multiple-criteria lookup. This [post of mine](http://yoursumbuddy.com/index-sumproduct-or-index-match-for-multiple-criteria-lookups/) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I commend @Doug Glancy's post but since you have mentioned VLOOKUP for the time being you may appreciate the choice of something with which you may be more familiar, though it involves adding a helper column and in many cases INDEX/MATCH is better:

Insert a column (A) in your Sheet 2 and, assuming no labels in either sheet (data starts in Row1) put `=B1&C1` in A1 and copy down to suit.

In Sheet 1 Row1 and to the right of your data (assumed to be in ColumnsA:B) put:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1&B1,'Sheet 2'!A:D,4,0),"")
```

and copy down to suit. Instead of struggling with multiple column referencing this is equivalent to single column referencing, with the sheet 1 'column' created within the formula. The 'engine' is wrapped within an IFERROR so that where the combination does not exist in Sheet 2 no error message is shown.